# How To Adding Search Functionality to MvxListView - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, search, xamarin, mvxlistview

I have created list and bind that to my layout it works fine now I want to implement search functionality in MvxListView
-Code
-Models

```
public class Language
{
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}
```

In Language Service Class

```
public async Task GetAllLanguageList(Action<ObservableCollection<Language>> successAction, Action<Exception> errorAction)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Language> AllLanguageList = new ObservableCollection<Language>();
        AllLanguageList.Add(new Language { Lang = "Spanish"});
        AllLanguageList.Add(new Language { Lang = "Portuguese"});
        AllLanguageList.Add(new Language { Lang = "Manadarin"});
        AllLanguageList.Add(new Language { Lang = "English"});

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        successAction(AllLanguageList);
    }
```

In my View Model I have done all these thinks for binding

```
public ObservableCollection<Language> AllLanguageList { get; private set; }
AllLanguageList = new ObservableCollection<Language>();
```

All code works fine
Now I want to implement Search

In My client Side

```
edit_text_search = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit_text_search);
edit_text_search.TextChanged += InputSearch_TextChanged;

private void InputSearch_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //What should I write here?
}
```

Xaml code

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource LanguageList"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mainlist_template_all" />
```

Comment: Just filter your ItemsSource that you are binding to the ListView.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron, Thanks for your replay.
Can you please tell me how can I do that from Xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution would be:

1. Instead of binding to `AllLanguageList` bind to a new `FilteredLanguageList`
2. Whenever someone enters something in a search box or text field filter `AllLanguageList` and overwrite contents of `FilteredLanguageList`

So very naive and primitively:

```
private List<string> _filteredLanguageList;
public List<string> FilteredLanguageList
{
    get => _filteredLanguageList;
    set 
    {
        _filteredLanguageList = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _searchQuery;
public string SearchQuery
{
    get => _searchQuery;
    set
    {
        _searchQuery = value;
        FilterLanguages(_searchQuery);
    }
}
```

In your XAML bind your `ListView` `ItemsSource` to `FilteredLanguageList`, and bind your `Entry` `Text` property to `SearchQuery`.

Then implement your filtering of languages in `FilterLanguages`. Something like this could work, but you need to adjust to your liking:

```
private void FilterLanguages(string query)
{
    FilteredLanguageList = AllLanguageList.Where(l =>
        l.Lang.ToLowerInvariant()
            .Contains(
                query.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();
}
```